# PHP save a txt file on desktop

Tags: php

It's possible save a string as text file and save the file on desktop?

I have found only questions about ow to save the file in the server.

I've tried but without luck

Comment: What have you tried? Use [file_set_contents()](http://php.net/file_set_contents). (This won't work of course if you mean the user's desktop.)

Comment: by desktop do you mean the user's system or the actual desktop folder of a user? because you cannot decide where the user wants to download a file

Comment: Are you asking about server side PHP and the client's desktop? Or are you asking about a PHP application that runs on the same computer as the desktop in question?

Comment: @ComFreek: Did you mean [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) :)?

Comment: Hmm, I see there is an answer accepted! So the desktop is actually on the server, therefore the question answered itself. I doubt there is need to keep this further, see as well [save the file in users desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986194/save-the-file-in-users-desktop?rq=1) for the keywords.

Comment: @hakre Oh, right ;) I second the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//CREATE

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
```

//WRITE

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = 'This is the data';
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

[DEMO](http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete)

Comment: So the desktop is actually on the server, therefore the question answered itself. Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force the download location of a file on a users computer, but you can force download a file prompt and have the user choose where to put the file.

This seems to be similar to the following question, where the answer is to 'force download' the file:

```
$file_url = 'http://www.myremoteserver.com/file.txt';
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
```

[How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Comment: This won't cause the file to be downloaded to the *desktop* though, and since the question explicitly says it is a text file you should use a more appropriate content-type for your example.

Comment: noted, couple of edits made to clarify

Comment: Of all the extensions, you used an `.exe`. **#LOL**

Comment: If it's a text file, there's no need for `Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary`

Comment: This more os less answears asked question. So nice to know many people accually help instead of dovnvoting. Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side.

But you could output a .txt file as download. Saving location will be defined by the user.

Check this: http://www.richnetapps.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).